# Hide arrow button in ComboBox in C#, VS2008

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, combobox

I need to hide the arrow button of a ComboBox.

I want `DropDownStyle` property to be equal `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList` whithout drop down arrow being visible. Can I do that?

Is there any other control that I may use to display a drop down list of images?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which UI framework is this? WinForms, WPF, ...?

Comment: Did you try changing the dropdownstyle property value to simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and fake it. Cover it with a `Textbox` and in the `Textbox's` GotFocus() event, simply set `comboBox.Focus()`

Answer (score 2):

Try setting DropDownStyle = Simple and Height to display only one line (about 24px).

Answer (score 0):

you can create an extended control or can override paint event of combobox in your form for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Popup control to display what you want.

For WPF: [Popup Control at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.CONTROLS.PRIMITIVES.POPUP%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true).

For Winform: [Simple Popup at CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/simplepopup.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For WinForms, you might like this class based on a button that pops up your items in a context menu and then takes selected item's text for the button text:

```
public class DropList : Button
{
    public event EventHandler TextChangedByUser;
    private ContextMenu _CM = new ContextMenu();
    private string[] _Items;

    public string[] Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set
        {
            _Items = value;
            _CM.MenuItems.Clear();
            foreach (string sChoice in _Items)
            {
                MenuItem MI = _CM.MenuItems.Add(sChoice, MI_Click);
            }
        }
    }

    private void MI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Text != (sender as MenuItem).Text)
        {
            this.Text = (sender as MenuItem).Text;
            if (TextChangedByUser != null) TextChangedByUser.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        _CM.Show(this, new System.Drawing.Point(0, this.Height - 1));
    }
}
```